# Problem with find user in m365 powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I need help with my small script, I found the disable accounts in M365 and I want disable all products:

```
$userdis = Get-AzureADUser -All $True | Where-Object { $_.AccountEnabled -eq $false} | select UserPrincipalName| ft -HideTableHeaders
 
 
foreach ($user in $usrdis){
 
Write-Output $user
$licusr = get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $user | select -ExpandProperty licenses | ft AccountSkuId -HideTableHeaders
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $user -RemoveLicenses $licusr
 
}
```

And I have error: get-msoluser : User Not Found.  User: usera1@domain.com

Of course this user existing.

What is the problem in this script? Any idea?

I try chnage some variables and load data from file and problem still existing.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: get-msoluser : User Not Found. User: usera1@domain.com

First & Foremost, Script looks good to perform the required operation.

First, when I tried it in my environment, I received the similar error. I found an issue and reproduced successfully as shown below:

Before you may add or remove licenses for specific MsOl users, you must first connect to the MsOl service with the command:

```
$msolCredentials = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService –Credential $msolCredentials
```

[image]

**Note**: Install `Msol` module if it is not present in Windows Powershell:

`Install-Module MSOnline`

If still the issue is persisting, Check whether that particular user exists in Azure Active directory by using below script:

```
$UserprincipalName = "xxxxxxxx"
$User = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserprincipalName  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If ($User -ne $Null) { 
"User exists in AD"
} Else {
"User not found"}
```

[image]

If a license is not found in the list, an error message stating that it cannot be assigned is displayed. In that case, use the following command to check the list and assign/remove accordingly.

`Get-MsolAccountSku`

[image]